# Ubuntu 16.10 - Permanently decrease swap space - via commandline.

Tags: command-line, fstab, swap, 16.10

I accidently allocated too much swap space in my current install.

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                     8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb2                  8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5                  8:21   0 111.3G  0 part 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  31.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0  79.6G  0 lvm  /
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   487M  0 part /boot
```

How would I go about changing my swap space to say 8gb. I currently have 32gb of ram on the system and I do not see my self ever really using the swap. But I would like it there just in case.

Comment: use __gparted__ to decrease size of _swap_.

Comment: @George does that work for lvm disks?

Comment: You might install `system-config-lvm`. It's a GUI for LVM. In `terminal`, `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm`. Then open the Unity dash and type `lvm`.

Comment: yes it does, it would?